# bash script to strip out some characters

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Bash scripting. How can i get a simple while loop to go through a file with below content and strip out all character from T (including T) using sed

```
"2012-05-04T10:16:04Z"
"2012-04-05T15:27:40Z"
"2012-03-05T14:58:27Z"
"2011-11-29T15:04:09Z"
"2011-11-16T12:12:00Z"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Through sed,

```
sed 's/"\|T.*//g' file
```

`"`matches double quotes `\|` or `T.*` starts from the first `T` match all the characters upto the last. Replacing the matched characters with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Example:

```
$ echo '"2012-05-04T10:16:04Z"' | sed 's/"\|T.*//g'
2012-05-04
```

Comment: You can similarly remove the " out of the resulting text. For that to work, it may be interesting to know if you would ever expect other " to be present, before the "T". I know that the code shown doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

A simple awk command to do this:

```
awk -F '["T]' '{print $2}' file
2012-05-04
2012-04-05
2012-03-05
2011-11-29
2011-11-16
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash builtins:

```
while IFS='T"' read -r a a b; do echo "$a"; done < filename
```

Output:

```
2012-05-04
2012-04-05
2012-03-05
2011-11-29
2011-11-16
```